# Php facebook like button

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I'm creating a dynamic site with php/mysql. There are few article. So i want to show a facebook like button for every article. How do i do this.

article show with php:

```
echo "<h2><a href='readmore.php?post_id= ". $id ."'>$sub</a></h2>";
```

Anyone can help me.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the Facebook developer documentation or any of the myriad of articles talking about Facebook Like buttons?

Comment: http://google.com/search?q=facebook+like+button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following code for each your article, and like button will show on each article:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo "http://www.yousite.com/$yourArticleUrlHere"; ?>&layout=standard&show_faces=false&width=450&action=like&colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:60px;"></iframe>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: what error does it show .. see reference here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?href=<?= "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; width: 450px; height: 80px;"></iframe>';
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You could improve this answer by saying why it is a better answer than the one that has been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to include **Facebook JavaScript SDK** in the beginning, after opening *body* tag: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

I hope this code will help:

```
<?php
  // Facebook Like button HTML 5 syntax
  echo '<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.yourwebsite.com/readmore.php?post_id='.$id.'" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>';

 // Facebook Like button XFBML syntax
 echo '<fb:like href="http://www.yourwebsite.com/readmore.php?post_id='.$id.'" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>';
?>
```

Comment: How do i found Facebook javaScript SDK?